# Display Wordpress posts in a two column bootstrap row

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wanting to display Wordpress posts in a two column row using Bootstrap. Here's what I have, i feel it's close but the second post is displaying underneath the first one insead of displaying next to each other.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
              </a>
          <?php endif; ?>
                <h2 class="blog-post-title">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                      <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                  </h2>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why is your column element wrapped _around_ the loop? It should be _inside_ - you want one column element wrapped around every single post you output.

Comment: Well it is not actually "wrapped around" - the number of opening and closing `div` tags inside your while loop don't even match.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, i'm a novice at this so thank you for clarifying the error. Would you be able to post how the correct way of solving this via code?

Comment: As I said, if you want _one_ column for every post, then the element that "creates" a column, should be inside your loop, not outside of it.

Comment: Thanks, i've had a go at putting the col div inside the loop but no luck. Are you able to post how you would do it via code? It would be super helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :   the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                              <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                          </a>
                      <?php endif; ?>
                            <h2 class="blog-post-title">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                  <?php the_title(); ?>
                                </a>
                              </h2>
                            </div>
            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <p>There are no posts to show</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```